# Mongoose save function not saving modifications

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to modify a document in Mongoose, but the changes don't seem to be saving.  The function itself is definitely being called, and the error is null each time. Logging the change made before and after the ID is pushed to the array shows that it was added, but it isn't saving.

```
function(req, res) {
  var id = req.user._id;
  Moment.findOne({ _id: req.body.moment._id }, function (err, moment) {
    moment.comments[req.body.index].likes.push(id);
    moment.save(function(err) {
      console.log('saved');
      if (err) console.log(err);
        res.json(moment);
      });
    }
  })
};
```

Schema

```
var MomentSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    default: '',
    required: true
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  startTime: {
    type: Date,
    trim: true,
    required: true
  },
  endTime: {
    type: Date,
    trim: true,
    required: true
  },
  comments: {
    type: Array
  }
});
```

Comment: This code doesn't work on its own though...

Comment: have you tried comparing moment after save is complete? e.g. moment.save(function (err, newdoc) { console.log(newdoc.toObject() }) to see what it looks like after saving? It could be saving it but ignoring your additions because your schema is too strict

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong. You have to create a Mongo ObjectId from the given id. Try

```
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;

Moment.findOne({_id: new ObjectId(req.body.moment._id)}, function(err, moment) ....
```

In your Query MongoDB doesn't find a document matching your query. This will not throw an error, but you will receive an empty object.

Comment: according to op the query works. He says he checks before and after pushing to array so he must be getting an object back.

Comment: The query is correct.  As @chriskelly said, I was able to get the intended object.  The only thing that isn't working is the final save function.